# Triggering multiple animation and shape changes with CSS simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, css-animations

I am trying to create a site whose main page is a large vertical navigation bar, with buttons that scale with the height and width of the window. When one button is clicked, I want the other buttons to scale down vertically while a new section extends from the clicked button. Basically, when a new section is expanded on the site, I want the other buttons to contract to allow room for the new section and allow the buttons to stay within the overall height of the browser window.

I have figured out how to contract the buttons and extend a new section, however I am having trouble doing both at the same time, as well as applying the contracting animation to all buttons on the page except just one.

What I've currently got: 
http://codepen.io/erreib/pen/doqyyN

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
  <a href="#logo" id="logo" class="button-logo">Header logo</a>

<a href="#sectionspeaking" id="speaking" class="button-speaking">Speaking button</a>
 <a id="sectionspeaking" class="section-speaking"></a>

<a href="#sectionwriting" id="writing" class="button-writing">Writing button</a>
 <a id="sectionwriting" class="section-writing"></a>

<a href="#sectionabout" id="about" class="button-about">About button</a>
 <a id="sectionabout" class="section-about"></a>

<a href="#sectioncontact" id="contact" class="button-contact">Contact button</a>
 <a id="sectioncontact" class="section-contact"></a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
 html, body {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

#main {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 background: gray;
}

/* Logo section */

.button-logo {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20%;
 background: #EB008B;

 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;

 transition: height 1s ease;
}

.button-logo:target {
 height: 5%;
}

/* Speaking section */

.button-speaking {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20%;
 background: #EF2C78;

 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
}

.section-speaking {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 0%;
 background: black;

 transition: height 1s ease;
}

.section-speaking:target {
 height: 20%;
}

/* Writing section */

.button-writing {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20%;
 background: #F35866;

 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
}

.section-writing {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 0%;
 background: black;

 transition: height 1s ease;
}

.section-writing:target {
 height: 20%;

 transition: height 1s ease;
}

/* About section */

.button-about {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20%;
 background: #F68353;

 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
}

.section-about {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 0%;
 background: black;

 transition: height 1s ease;
}

.section-about:target {
 height: 20%;

 transition: height 1s ease;
}

/* Contact section */

.button-contact {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20%;
 background: #FAAF40;

 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
}

.section-contact {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 0%;
 background: black;

 transition: height 1s ease;
}

.section-contact:target {
 height: 20%;

 transition: height 1s ease;
}
```

Would I need to use Javascript to allow for something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best bet is to use a flex design.

It will make the relationship between elements automatic.

Also, you can save a lot of work if you use the classes to avoid repeating the same styles over and over.

One posibility

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* Logo section */
.button-logo {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background: #EB008B;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Speaking section */
.button-speaking {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background: #EF2C78;

  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Writing section */

.button-writing {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background: #F35866;

  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}


/* About section */

.button-about {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background: #F68353;

  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Contact section */

.button-contact {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background: #FAAF40;

  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}



.section {
  flex: 20% 1 1;
  transition: flex 1s;
  background: black;
}
.section:target {
  flex: 40% 1 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <a href="#logo" id="logo" class="button-logo">Header logo</a>

  <a href="#sectionspeaking" id="speaking" class="button-speaking">Speaking button</a>
  <a id="sectionspeaking" class="section-speaking section"></a>

  <a href="#sectionwriting" id="writing" class="button-writing">Writing button</a>
  <a id="sectionwriting" class="section-writing section"></a>

  <a href="#sectionabout" id="about" class="button-about">About button</a>
  <a id="sectionabout" class="section-about section"></a>

  <a href="#sectioncontact" id="contact" class="button-contact">Contact button</a>
  <a id="sectioncontact" class="section-contact section"></a>
</div>
```